# How to log actual target class name for Spring Data Repository when using CustomizableTraceInterceptor

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-aop

My motivation is to easily find out during maintenance of a large Spring Data Jpa project which Repository method generated given sql.

I have `CustomerRepository` as in GitHub [spring-data-examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/interceptors/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/interceptors).

I changed `CustomizableTraceInterceptor` to:

```
public @Bean CustomizableTraceInterceptor interceptor() {
    CustomizableTraceInterceptor interceptor = new CustomizableTraceInterceptor();
    interceptor.setHideProxyClassNames(true);
    interceptor.setEnterMessage("Entering $[targetClassShortName].$[methodName]()");
    return interceptor;
}
```

**I would like to see in the log:**

```
Entering CustomerRepository.save()
```

but instead I am getting:

```
Entering SimpleJpaRepository.save()
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by extending CustomizableTraceInterceptor:

```
import org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils;
import org.springframework.aop.interceptor.CustomizableTraceInterceptor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository;

public class MethodTraceInterceptor extends CustomizableTraceInterceptor {
    @Override
    protected Class<?> getClassForLogging(Object target) {
        Class<?> classForLogging = super.getClassForLogging(target);
        if (SimpleJpaRepository.class.equals(classForLogging)) {
            Class<?>[] interfaces = AopProxyUtils.proxiedUserInterfaces(target);
            if (interfaces.length > 0) {
                return interfaces[0];
            }
        }
        return classForLogging;
    }
}
```

but I find it strange that such overriding is necessary. Ideally Spring trace interceptors should resolve class for logging correctly, even for spring data repositories.

Comment: I added this Interceptor as a bean, but it doesn't log messages at all. When I use CustomizableTraceInterceptor, messages were logged at least but with SimpleJpaRepository class name.What am I missing?